# Copied sheet with userform won't insert data into new userform

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I'm having trouble with the userform copied to the new sheet to insert data in the new sheet.

The userform code is:

```
Sub userform_initialize()
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim aCell As Range
' dont know why this code, but helps the named ranges
    With Worksheets("MasterData")
        For i = 1 To LastColumn
            With .Columns(i)
            LastRow = Lookup.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                With Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LastRow, i))
                Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(LastRow, i)).Select
                Selection.CreateName Top:=True
                End With
            End With
        Next i
    End With
' defining the input to the combobox and lists from masterdata
    Me.ComboBoxName.RowSource = "Name"
    Me.ComboBoxTMS.RowSource = "TMS"
    Me.ComboBoxOtherT.RowSource = "Other_T"
    Me.ListBoxPlacement.RowSource = "Placement"
    
    

End Sub


Sub CommandSave_click()

' mandatory for picking name in userform
    If ComboBoxName.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must select a name"
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
    End If

'mandatory for writing hours in userform
    If TextBoxHours.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You need to type in hours"
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
    End If

'mandatory of either TMS or Other Timeregistration in userform
    If ComboBoxOtherT.Value = "" Then
    If ComboBoxTMS.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must select TMS or Other Timeregistration"
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
    End If
    End If

'manadatory for picking one in the listbox with placement for userform
    If Not IsAnythingSelected(ListBoxPlacement) Then
        MsgBox "Please select placement of workday"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
' calling the macro that inserts the data in the correct columns and rows.
    Call BSave

' Clear Values
    ComboBoxName.Value = ""
    ComboBoxTMS.Value = ""
    ComboBoxOtherT.Value = ""
    TextBoxHours.Value = ""
    TextBoxComments.Value = ""
    ListBoxPlacement.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub BSave()
    Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("McLys_Timeregistration") ' declaring which worksheet we are working on

    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

    ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = ComboBoxName.Text 'Adds into Col A & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = DTPicker1.Value 'Adds into Col B & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = TextBoxHours.Value 'Adds into Col C & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = ComboBoxTMS.Text 'Adds into Col D & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = ComboBoxOtherT.Text 'Adds into Col E & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = TextBoxComments.Text 'Adds into Col F & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = ListBoxPlacement.Text 'Adds into Col G & Last Blank Row

End Sub

' function for making sure that at least one of the choices are chosen in the listbox
Function IsAnythingSelected(lBox As Control) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim selected As Boolean
    selected = False
    For i = 1 To lBox.ListCount
        If lBox.selected(i) Then
            selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    IsAnythingSelected = selected
End Function

Sub CommandCancel_click()

    Unload Me ' making the userform closing

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
' every time the userform is activated it makes sure that its todays date there is in the calendar.
DTPicker1.Value = Date
End Sub
```

and for what i can see and have tried to change only in the code below the sheet name is mentioned

```
Private Sub BSave()
    Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("McLys_Timeregistration") ' declaring which worksheet we are working on

    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

    ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = ComboBoxName.Text 'Adds into Col A & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = DTPicker1.Value 'Adds into Col B & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = TextBoxHours.Value 'Adds into Col C & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = ComboBoxTMS.Text 'Adds into Col D & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = ComboBoxOtherT.Text 'Adds into Col E & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = TextBoxComments.Text 'Adds into Col F & Last Blank Row
    ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = ListBoxPlacement.Text 'Adds into Col G & Last Blank Row

End Sub
```

can anyone tell me where the problem is? if i change the sheet name here its still inserting the information into the old sheet.

in the sheet only this is mentioned to call the userform:

```
Sub shape_button()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Sub placeUser()
With UserForm1
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
  .Show
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you call the new userform? Did you go through your code step by step using F8? Either you run the wrong code or it happens something else that you expected to happen. Checkout [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)

Comment: i have tried, where i call the new userform, and there was no errors, i dont know how to go through the F8 in a userform, because i need the data in the userform before it can insert so i can see why it inserts wrong.

Comment: just put a break point in the first line of your `CommandSave_click` procedure. If you click the button after editing data it will stop there and you can go through from there pressing F8. Actually learning how to basically debug your code is necessary to give us more information about what exactly is wrong, so I suggest to read the link I gave and try using the debugging features VBA has.